# Ruby is_a? vs ===

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, operators

What is the difference between `is_a?` and `===`?

Running this code:

```
puts myObj.class
puts myObj.is_a?(Hash)
puts myObj === Hash   #Curious 
puts Hash  === myObj
```

The output is:

```
Hash
true
false        #Why?
true
```

Comment: Many style guides recommend not using === in your code, as it's slated for use in the built-in case construct.

Answer (score 11):

Many of Ruby's built-in classes, such as String, Range, and Regexp, provide their own implementations of the `===` operator, also known as case-equality, triple equals or threequals. Because it's implemented differently in each class, it will behave differently depending on the type of object it was called on. Generally, it returns true if the object on the right "belongs to" or "is a member of" the object on the left. For instance, it can be used to test if an object is an instance of a class (or one of its subclasses).

```
String === "zen"  # Output: => true
Range === (1..2)   # Output: => true
Array === [1,2,3]   # Output: => true
Integer === 2   # Output: => true
```

The same result can be achieved with other methods which are probably best suited for the job. It's usually better to write code that is easy to read by being as explicit as possible, without sacrificing efficiency and conciseness.

```
2.is_a? Integer   # Output: => true
2.kind_of? Integer  # Output: => true
2.instance_of? Integer # Output: => false
```

Notice the last example returned false because integers such as 2 are instances of the `Fixnum` class, which is a subclass of the `Integer` class. The `===`, `is_a?` and `kind_of?` methods return true if the object is an instance of the given class or any subclasses. The `instance_of?` method is stricter and only returns true if the object is an instance of that exact class, not a subclass.

The `is_a?` and `kind_of?` methods are implemented in the `Kernel` module, which is mixed in by the `Object` class. Both are aliases to the same method. Let's verify:

```
Kernel.instance_method(:kind_of?) == Kernel.instance_method(:is_a?)
# Output: => true
```

More info at [this blog post about ruby operators.](http://www.zenruby.info/2016/05/ruby-operators-equality-comparison.html)

Comment: Excellent answer.

To nitpick a bit though, I think that these methods are implemented on `Object` rather than `Kernel`:
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html (none of these methods shown)
- https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Object (all of these methods shown)

But, I could be mistaken!

Comment: Hi David. You can see those methods in `Kernel.public_methods.sort`. Additionally, if you do `'foo'.method(:is_a?).owner` (same for the other methods), it returns `Kernel`.

Answer (score 3):

They are mostly the same in essence, but `===` can also be overridden in subclasses.

`===` is usually a light wrapper around something, mainly so that the case construct can use it implicitly. By default it's a [wrapper around](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) `Object#is_a?` (see source).

These two however are *intended* to be equivalent constructs.

Comment: The [default implementation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Module.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) `mod === obj` actually calls `obj.is_a?(mod)`

Comment: @Stefan yes, that's why I've called it a wrapper. Maybe I should clarify that it's a wrapper around `is_a?`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Clear example

```
1)$> Integer === 1 # => true 

2)$> 1 === Integer # => false
```

1) 1 **is an instance of** Integer, but 2) Integer is not an instance of 1.

But also returns true if **is an instance of any of its subclasses**, for example:

```
$ > Numeric === 1   # => true 
$ > Numeric === 1.5 # => true

$ > Fixnum === 1    # => true 
$ > Fixnum === 1.5  # => false
```